# Creating a polar chart / polar grid

Tags: modeling, mathematics, geometry-nodes

Is there a way to create a polar grid / polar chart in Blender 2.93.1?  I know I can create a circle and do several insets then draw the lines. I was wondering if there was a better way that can make it adjustable, maybe with geometry nodes.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Which parameters do you need adjustable? Line width/spacing/sth else?

Comment: @JachymMichal  The line width and the spacing.

Answer (score 3):

I've had to come up with a solution for that some time ago and it turns out the algorithm is not that trivial. I based it on the Ruby implementation from the excellent Mazes For Programmers book by Jamis Buck.

I'm sure there are simpler ways to do this but I understand add-ons suggestions are allowed here. Full disclaimer, I wrote that add-on. (It's free to download, use and modify).

Download the Maze Generator add-on from https://github.com/Gorgious56/MazeGenerator/releases/tag/0.4.0

Install it like any other add-on. Tested on version 2.93.1. Open the "N" panel with <kbd>N</kbd> and look for a panel named "MG".

In the panel Parameters, set the cell type to "Polar". A polar maze should be generated.

[image]

We don't want the walls so you can go ahead and hide them. Click on the eye icon in the walls sub-panel and go into wireframe mode to see your polar grid.

[image]

Add a Weld modifier and a Wireframe modifier with "Replace Original" unchecked and "Material Offset" to 1 to get this :

[image]

You'll have to set the display type to "Uniform" and the color to pure white to get this effect.

[image]

You can then control the "Branching" amount

[image]

You can also extend the grid size :

[image]